# С помощью jQuery добавить в кэш параметр

Tags: jquery, кэширование

Здравствуйте все! Мне нужна помощь с кэш. Мне нужно в кэш сохранить параметр (это цифра) и обнавления сайта необходимо взять этот параметр. Нужно сделать это с помощью jQuery.

Comment: Что за параметр? В какой именно кэш хотите сохранять?

Comment: не знаю в какой кэш, пример когда заходиш в сайт и незнаю кликаеш кудато и он дает тебе цифру 10 на странице, потом ты обнавляеш сайт и эта цифра остается на сайте

Comment: что то в этом роде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать куки (cookies).

Подключение

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Работа с cookies

```
// запись и перезапись значений
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');

// получить значение по имени:
$.cookie('cookie_name');

// удаление значений
$.cookie('cookie_name', null);
```

Comment: помоему это точто я хочу спосибо огромное

Comment: JQuery-Cookie был переименован в https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/commit/6d5b9190b446b68e13b45d0b7d78c7ba4a62cb65